# My Drupal site's css basepath

Tags: jquery, css, .htaccess, drupal

I'm using Drupal 7 and i'm moving my site new host. But when i click my site, not working my custom css.

Normally:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite.net/sites/default/files/css/mycss.css" media="all" />
```

But my code in this:

```
    <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
    jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"en\/","ajaxPageState":
//MY CODES//
    //--><!]]>
```

What's my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The permission of the default directory is 555 so this is not accessible publicly. You can place it else where like in the themes directory.But don't give the publicly permission to the default directory as the settings.php is inside the default directory.